# Whenever I react to an embed, It sends double messages. [DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message]

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a waifu command where it gets an image and a name and puts it in a embed, it also then reacts with the  emoji. I wanted to make it so the first person who clicked the emoji would claim the waifu.

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed, ReactionCollector} = require('discord.js');
const {
    prefix
} = require('../../config');
const superagent = require('superagent');
const {
    urlencoded
} = require('body-parser');


module.exports = {
    name: 'waifu',
    category: 'waifu',
    description: 'Random Waifu',
    usage: `${prefix}waifu`,
    perms: 'Send Messages',
    cooldown: 5,
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

        const rating1 = 10
        const rating2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * rating1)
        var rating = rating2

        const decimals1 = 100
        const decimals2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * decimals1)
        var decimals = decimals2

        const compatibility1 = 100
        const compatibility2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * compatibility1)
        var compatibility = compatibility2

        const {
            waifuID
        } = require("../../Database/WaifuNameDB.json")

        let randW = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(waifuID).length)
        let randomWaifu = waifuID[randW]

        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${randomWaifu.names}`)
            .addField("Claims:", `${randomWaifu.claims}`)
            .addField("Rating:", `${rating}.${decimals}/10 ⭐`)
            .setImage(`${randomWaifu.img_url}`, innerHeight = '500', innerWidth = '500')
            .setColor('#f095d1')
            .setFooter(`| Powered by: @Twintails API `, `https://64.media.tumblr.com/1a1c3bcc08b5a048b90139a56fe7f415/tumblr_o9ku1rVS8z1vnqjx7o2_250.png`)

        var mg = await message.channel.send(embed2);
        
        mg.react('')

        message.delete()

        bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.mg) await reaction.mg.fetch();
            if (reaction) await reaction.fetch()
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {

                message.channel.send(`${randomWaifu.names} was claimed!`)

                mg.delete()
            if(user = message.author) return;

            }
        })
        
    }   
}
```

It works, but if for example I do /waifu, it sends the embed and says (waifuname) was claimed, but whenever I do /waifu again, everything is the same, but when I click the react button, it says that the previous and the current waifu was claimed.
https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business6/uploads/glitch/original/2X/9/98363d9496747899fe23698cb0f98846b1e7136c.jpeg

(Umaru Doma was the previous waifu I rolled)

It also gives an error:
`(node:9964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message`

Please help if you can!

Comment: can you explain `/waifu` further? I don't understand what you mean, is it the same string inside the require statement that grabs the json?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the json or /waifu command at all, It's only the claim part thats messed up.

Comment: The code in question is the messageReactionAdd function. (That's what I think)

Comment: All I want it to do is, whoever clicks the  first, gets the waifu, and in chat it says: HK married <waifu name>

Comment: oh `/waifu` is the command you type in the discord chat, that's the input your bot responds to

Comment: yes, you do /waifu, the bot sends an embed and reacts with  on the embed

Comment: So, is there any way you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to fix this everyone!

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {
            
            if(user.bot) return;
            const {
                message,
                emoji
            } = messageReaction;

            if (emoji.name === "") {
                if (!message.id === mg.id) return;
                if (message.id === mg.id) {

                    mg.delete()
                    message.channel.send(`${randomWaifu.names} was claimed!`)
                }
            }
        });
```